# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null for smooth scroll effect using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, web-deployment

I'm creating a smooth scroll effect using JS but on the execution of the code I'm facing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

what the actual problem is?

```
function smooothScroll(target,duration){
    var target = document.querySelector(target);
    var targetPosition = target.getBoundingClientReact().top;
    var startingPositon = window.pageyOffset;
    var distance = targetPosition - startingPositon;
    var startTime = null;

    function animation(currentTime){
        if (startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
        var timeElapesd = currentTime - startTime;
        var run = ease(timeElapesd,startingPositon,distance,duration);
        window.scrollTo(0,run); 
    if (timeElapesd < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }   

    function ease(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
        t -= 2;
        return -c/2 * (t*t*t*t - 2) + b;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    
}
var section1 = document.querySelector('.section1');

section1.addEventListener('click', function() {

   smooothScroll('.section1',3000);

});

<body>
    <div class="box1">
        <a href="#" class="section1">Click Me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <a href="#" class="section2">Thanks for Clicking Me</a>
        <img src="cat.jpg" alt="" class="img">
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why didn't you considered css for this ? .... html { scroll-behavior:  smooth }

Comment: Well, I'm new to JS and I'm practicing by creating small (project-type) codes to get a well grip on JS. BTW I used HTML { scroll-behavior: smooth } many times in my project.

Comment: Just wanted to ask when are you lading your script before ? If yes then try pasting your scriptjust before closing tag of body .. also you have some typo  instead of `target.getBoundingClientReact()` write `target.getBoundingClientRect()` .... Also when clicking a link u might consider pelrevebt the default action of the link !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some syntax error inside `smooothScroll` function:

- you have `target` parameter and then also declare the same  variable inside function which is confusing and not recommended
- `getBoundingClientRect` instead of `getBoundingClientReact`

**Recommended:** try to use block scope variable `(let, const)` instead of global scope variable `var`.

```js
function smooothScroll(selector,duration){
    const targetEle = document.querySelector(selector);
    console.log(targetEle.getBoundingClientRect());
    const targetPosition = targetEle.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const startingPositon = window.pageyOffset;
    const distance = targetPosition - startingPositon;
    let startTime = null;

    function animation(currentTime){
        if (startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
        var timeElapesd = currentTime - startTime;
        var run = ease(timeElapesd,startingPositon,distance,duration);
        window.scrollTo(0,run); 
    if (timeElapesd < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }   

    function ease(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
        t -= 2;
        return -c/2 * (t*t*t*t - 2) + b;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    
}

var section1 = document.querySelector('.section1');

section1.addEventListener('click', function() {

   smooothScroll('.section1',3000);

});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="box1">
        <a href="#" class="section1">Click Me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <a href="#" class="section2">Thanks for Clicking Me</a>
        <img src="cat.jpg" alt="" class="img">
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Man for the Help and suggestions. It was really worth it.